# how to get the ID of the record that is update in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am able to get a sql query that can return the ID of a record that is update in the Database; that ID is needed to update other records.

```
public int updateCases(int id,string fname)
{
 string query="update bio_data set firstName=@fname OUTPUT INSERTED.ID where id=@ID";
    int IDValue = 0;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname",fname);
        
        IDValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());  // this is incorrect because it always return one
        if (IDValue <= 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return IDValue; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        error.Text = "An Error Occur while update a case Bio_data!!" + ex.Message;
        error.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        return 0;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
```

but I don't know how to get that updated ID value in C#.

Comment: why you want updated ID when you know id?

Comment: the IDs are different, the one in the paramter should have been CaseID
but I need the Auto increment ID, which I need to update other records in another table.

Comment: You send `@ID` to get the same id? Why?

Comment: So you basically want `"SELECT ID FROM bio_data WHERE CaseID = @ID"`? We don't know the table structure and by convention we assume that `ID` refers to the primary key of a table. Or what do you mean by "Auto increment ID"? An `UPDATE` doesn't auto increment anything.

Comment: cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() will return the number of rows affected (inserted/updated/deleted).

You already have the ID.

Comment: It is an _update_. So the _id_ you are using to update will not change.

Comment: You are passing `@ID`, so why are you again want that ID back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* you're really asking how do you retrieve the resultset returned by an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` with an `OUTPUT` clause. You use `ExecuteReader` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`

Here's simplified example:

### Create a test table

```
SELECT * INTO Test FROM (VALUES (1, 'ABC'),(2,'DEF'),(3,'ABC')) A(Id, Val)
```

### C# code

Update where `Val` is `'ABC'` returning the rows updated and print them (excuse the suspect error handling etc)

```
var conString = ...;
var query = "UPDATE TEST SET Val ='XYZ' OUTPUT INSERTED.* WHERE Val = @Val";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{

    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val", "ABC");

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader["id"] + " " + reader["Val"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Prints

```
1 XYZ
3 XYZ
```

And `SELECT * FROM Test` now shows

```
Id          Val
----------- ----
1           XYZ
2           DEF
3           XYZ
```

Hope this helps. You should be aware that this approach can have issues with triggers and raising/handling of SQL errors.